# How can I use fastify-jwt to sign a token with expiredtime?

Tags: jwt, fastify

If we dont need expiredIn,just use this way that I can create a token

```
const token = await reply.jwtSign(userJSON)
```

But I want to give a time that token should disabled:expiredIn!
What should I do to give a expiredTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-jwt)

> expiresIn: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span zeit/ms. Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d". A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms").

you have to use the `expiresIn`option in the call to `jwtSign`, e.g.:

```
const token = await reply.jwtSign(userJSON, { expiresIn: '1h' })
```

for a token that expires in 1 hour.